# Как парсить команды внутри приложения Go?

Tags: golang

Как парсить команды внутри приложения Go? Допустим `print=hello` и должно вывести *hello*, `count=hello` - должно подсчитать сколько символов в строке. Пробовал конструкцией `if, else if`, но это не то что мне нужно, потому чтобы давать дополнительный аргумент нужно инициализировать новый оператор `if`. Аргументы командной строки мне не нужны. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант 1

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

var cmds = make(map[string]func(string))

func main() {
    // заполняем команды

    cmds["print"] = func(s string) {
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
    cmds["count"] = func(s string) {
        fmt.Println(len(s))
    }

    // ... ещё очень много команд ...

    // выполняем команды
    for _, arg := range os.Args[1:] {
        cmd := strings.Split(arg, "=")
        if len(cmd) != 2 {
            fmt.Println(arg, "не понимаю... ")
            continue
        }

        // для красноречия
        name := cmd[0]
        param := cmd[1]

        // ищем функцию
        fn := cmds[name]
        if fn == nil {
            fmt.Println(name, "не знаю... ")
            continue
        }

        // исполняем команду
        fn(param)
    }
}
```

Вариант два

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

// пустая карта ассоциаций строк с функциями
var cmds = make(map[string]func(string))

func main() {
    // заполняем команды

    // создаём функцию для печати
    // в карте созадём ассоциацию между строкой "print" 
    // и функцией выполняющей команду
    cmds["print"] = func(s string) {
        fmt.Println(s)
    }

    // создаём функцию для подсчёта
    // в карту записываем ассоциацию между строкой "count" 
    // и функцией выполняющей команду
    cmds["count"] = func(s string) {
        fmt.Println(len(s))
    }

    // ...

    // выполняем команды
    for {

        var arg string
        _, err := fmt.Scan(&arg) // читаем ввод пользователя
        // fmt.Scan() останавливается на пробеле
        // что позволяет вводить несколько команд в одной строке

        if err != nil { // обязательно проверям на ошибки
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }

        // спец команда для выхода
        if arg == "exit" {
            return
        }

        // разбиваем введённую строку на до и после "="
        cmd := strings.Split(arg, "=")

        if len(cmd) != 2 { // проверяем что у нас 2 елемента в слайсе
            // жалуемся если это не так
            fmt.Println(arg, "не понимаю... ")
            continue
        }

        name := cmd[0]  // 1й елемент слайса это имя команды на пр. "print"
        param := cmd[1] // 2й елемент слайса это параметр на пр. "hello"

        fn := cmds[name] // смотрим есть ли у нас функция с таким именем name
        if fn == nil {   // если мы такой функции не знаем то cmds[name] возвращает nil
            fmt.Println(name, "не знаю... ")
            continue
        }

        // если функция с именем name существует то теперь fn 
        // это функция кторую мы можем
        // напряму использовать

        // исполняем fn функцию с параметром param
        fn(param)

    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо) А можно же сделать при помощи fmt.Scanln()? чтоб искало не как аргумент командной строки, в как case или if, else

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю что вы предлагаете :). Предложите код.  Давайте посмотрим.

Comment: у вас тут такая сложна система, не могу разобраться) Вот что-то на подобие того что я хочу сделать - https://pastebin.com/vsM76Sku

Comment: тогда вот изменённый вариант https://pastebin.com/RtmcT2vq я постараюсь описать более подробно

Comment: спасибо большое! Тоже самое делал с предыдущим кодом, только он был под циклом, нужно было всеголишь убрать цикл)

Comment: а если допустим мне нужно несколько аргументов? Пример: `print=hello count=hello` то есть сразу два аргумента выполнить.

Comment: вариант два в ответе заменяем на `fmt.Scan()` который просто останавливается на пробеле, т.е. когда он видит `print=hello count=hello` он считывает `print=hello` останавливатся и потом далее читает `print=hello`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72128/discussion-between-biosckon-and-jack-anderson).